# Discrepancy between Sefer HaMitzvos and Sefer Hachinuch

Tags: rambam, mitzvah, korban, ramban, sefer-hachinuch

The **Rambam** in **Sefer HaMitzvos**, *Lo Saaseh* 148 writes that a non-Kohen who eats *kodshim*/holy food breaks a negative *mitzvah*:

> שהזהירנו שלא לאכול זר מבשר קדשי הקדשים. והוא אמרו יתעלה וזר לא יאכל כי קדש הם. ואינו חייב מלקות עד שיאכל בעזרה אחר זריקת דמים.‏

I went to check the **Sefer HaChinuch** on this *mitzvah* to see what he says, and I couldn't find it. I checked the Frankel Rambam and they wrote in a footnote that the **Sefer HaChinuch** left out this *mitzvah*!

The **Chinuch** writes at the beginning that he based his sefer off the **Rambam**. He'll point out when the **Ramban** disagrees and sometimes will side with the **Ramban**, but will still write the **Rambam**'s *mitzvah*. This is the only exception that I'm aware of.

Do any of the commentators explain why he left it out? Even the **Ramban** seems to agree with counting it, since he didn't write any objections. As well, which *mitzvah* did the **Chinuch** replace it with? The Frankel Rambam in the footnote I mentioned writes that in `דרך מצותיך ח"ד סי' תפז` it's written which mitzvah replaces it. This seems to be [the sefer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derech_Mitzvosecha) of the [Tzemach Tzedek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menachem_Mendel_Schneersohn), but from what I found online it doesn't have a fourth chelek/section.

Comment: https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%97%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%9A#.D7.94.D7.9E.D7.A6.D7.95.D7.95.D7.94_.D7.94.D7.A0.D7.95.D7.A1.D7.A4.D7.AA

Comment: @Double-AA Interesting, unfortunately they don't bring a source for their assertions. That means the Chinuch's version of Sefer HaMitzvos had 612 mitzvos? Strange theory. Where is this Rabbeinu Avraham?

Comment: I think their claim is the Chinukh's version of Sefer HaMitzvot had 613 and [mistakenly] included the prohibition of Pesach on a Bamah.

Comment: robev, maybe you should edit in this post as the source for wikipedia

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This discrepancy was noticed by the **Mishneh LaMelech** in his **Parshas Derachim** [*Derech Mitzvosecha* 4:487](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30749&st=&pgnum=261), and the [**Minchas Chinuch** § 487](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37518&st=&pgnum=130&hilite=), among others.

As mentioned, the **Chinuch** leaves out the *mitzvah* against a *zar* eating *kodshim*, and he replaces it with the prohibition against bringing the Pesach offering on a private altar. He brings this as *Mitzvah* #467.

The **Mishneh LaMelech** and [**Rav Yerucham Fischel Perla**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yerucham_Fishel_Perlow) (in his comments to [**Sefer HaMitzvos LeRasag** *Lo Sa'aseh* § 174](https://www.sefaria.org/Commentary_on_Sefer_Hamitzvot_of_Rasag%2C_Negative_Commandments.174.2)) explain that the **Rambam** and others left this *mitzvah* out because they felt it was only stated for a specific time (following *Shoresh* 3), ie: when private altars were permitted. The question is, why did the **Chinuch** include it, especially since he was so loyal to the **Rambam**? This in addition to the fact that the **Chinuch** doesn't even acknowledge his deviation from the **Rambam** (and **Ramban**).

[**Rav Chaim Heller**](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%A8), in his [introduction](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38151&st=&pgnum=3) to his version of **Sefer HaMitzvos**, explains that soon after **Sefer HaMitzvos** was published and subsequently translated, mistakes began to appear. He cites the Responsum of [**Rabbeinu Avraham ben HaRambam**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_Maimonides) ([**Maaseh Nissim** § 2](https://tablet.otzar.org/en/book/book.php?book=158148&pagenum=4)) to [**Rav Daniel HaBavli**](https://www.encyclopedia.com/religion/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/daniel-ben-saadiah-ha-bavli) who asked why the **Rambam** counted the prohibition of bringing the Pesach offering on a private altar when the *mitzvah* wasn't for all time. **Rabbeinu Avraham** responded that there is no such *mitzvah* in the *sefer* of the **Rambam** and it's entirely a mistake. **Rav Heller** assumes that **Rav Daniel HaBavli** had a version of **Sefer HaMitzvos** with this mistake in it, and suggests that perhaps this mistake was also in the version the **Sefer HaChinuch** had. This would explain why the **Sefer HaChinuch** deviated from the **Rambam** that we have (although this is not a definitive explanation, it's the best I found).

(Credit to the Frankel edition of the **Rambam** for providing a lot of the sources.)

---

I subsequently found the **ArtScroll** version of **Sefer HaChinuch** points to a different approach to this discrepancy, found in [**Mayan HaChochmah**](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20823&st=&pgnum=232&hilite=) by [**Rav Noach Chaim Tzvi Berlin**](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A0%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A6%D7%91%D7%99_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9F), which is as follows:

The **Chinuch** noticed the **Rambam** left out all the laws of private altars, yet codifies the law prohibiting the Pesach offering on a private altar. This must mean that private altars are no longer relevant today as it is anyways forbidden to bring an offering outside the Temple. Since the **Rambam** specifically codified the law pertaining to the Pesach offering, that law must be relevant even today.

The **Chinuch** must also hold like [**Tosafos**](https://www.sefaria.org/Tosafot_on_Zevachim.59a.37.1) in **Zevachim** 59a, who say everyone agrees that someone today who slaughters an offering outside the Temple is exempt from *kares*. Therefore, the prohibition pertaining to the Pesach offering would be a novelty, punished by *kares*, making it fitting to count in the 613 *mitzvos*. However, the **Rambam** disagrees with **Tosafos** and holds slaughtering an offering today outside the Temple does get punished with *kares*. That means there's nothing unique about the Pesach offering. It's just an extra prohibition, which isn't worth counting in the 613.

All this explains why the **Chinuch** added this mitzvah, but not why he discounted a *zar* eating *kodshim*. The **Mayan HaChochmah** (I can't find where) says that the **Chinuch** held that that verse ([**Exodus** 29:33](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.29.33)) is referring to the *miluim*, the inaugural korbonos ceremony. Therefore, that prohibition was only for that time, and isn't to be counted in 613 (**ArtScroll** cites **Maharam Schik** [#103](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37469&st=&pgnum=85&hilite=) who also says this).

However, **ArtScroll** points out this is hard to understand, as the first half of that verse **is** counted by the **Chinuch** as a *mitzvah*, meaning not exclusively about the *miluim*. Why wouldn't this part of the verse be treated the same. They subsequently point to **Maharam Schik** #103 for a possible resolution, although I don't get how he resolves it (he says it's just a ייתור דקרא so not worth counting).

All of this fails to explain why the **Sefer HaChinuch** in both locations doesn't notify us that he's deviating from the **Rambam**.

Of course, the first explanation seems a lot simpler and is thus [more likely](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor) to be correct.